# Sending Email (unicode) From dot net application

Tags: .net, email, unicode, xslt

How can I send email in multiple languages from my .net application using an xsl/xslt file to format the e-mail message?

I experience an error when I send emails in Russian, I can see the Russian Characters in Hotmail and OutLook properly. But I can't see them in gmail and yahoo mail.

What changes do I need to make to correctly render Russian Characters in gmail and yahoo mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this samples : http://www.example-code.com/csharp/RussianEmail.asp

I assume you are already setting the Charset and file encoding..

```
email.Charset = "koi8-r";
```

May be encode everything as default Russian encoding of iso-8859-5. For testing purpose hardcode email body with some Russian Characters and save the source code file Unicode (code page 1200) from File - Advanced Save Options...

Comment: btw , my function is used for many language (Chinese, danish, Turkish .. etc). can I use this one you suggest?

Comment: Then I need to tell you , I am using Visual Studio 2005. How can I declare Charset for System.net.MailMessage object? Another thing if I set encoding="iso-8859-5" in xsl. I do save source code file Unicode (code page 1200) , encoding automatically changed to "utf-16". Is it right? Best Wishes!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your charset to `UTF-8`. it supports all of the live languages in the world, but in most cases it is 2-byte. But for English and some other languages (including russian - I'm not sure) it is 1-byte